# Size of the smallest union chain containing a family

Tags: co.combinatorics

A family of sets $\mathcal{F}$ is a *union chain* if each set in $\mathcal{F}$ of size at least $2$ is the union of two other sets in $\mathcal{F}$. That is, $X\in \mathcal{F}$ and $|X|\geq 2$, then $X=Y\cup Z$ for some $Y,Z\in \mathcal{F}$ and $Y,Z\neq X$.

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a family of sets. 
Let $|\mathcal{A}|=n$ and $\left|\bigcup_{A\in \mathcal{A}} A\right|=m$.

What are some upper bounds for $|\mathcal{F}|$ in terms of $n$ and $m$, where $\mathcal{F}$ is the smallest union chain that contains $\mathcal{A}$? Is $|\mathcal{F}| = O(m+n)$?

The terminology comes from [addition chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition_chain), but instead of addition we have set unions.

Comment: By binary division, each set in A having k elements can be represented as a union chain of about 2k  many sets, so there is an upper bound on the sum of the sizes of the sets.  Some savings can be realized by using shared sets of size 2,4,8 and so on.  I would be surprised if O(n+m) is always achievable.  Gerhard "Chain Isn't The Best Word" Paseman, 2020.05.12.